# What is the most efficient way to store and print a value after splitting?

Tags: ruby

I have a path like this:

> **"/cygwin/home/learn/xyz"**

and I want:

> **dir1** = "home" and **dir2** = "xyz"

So I wrote this ruby code to get the output:

```
    path = "/cygwin/home/learn/xyz"
    a = path.split(/\//)
    dir1 = a[2]
    puts dir1    #home
    dir2 = a[4]  
    puts dir2    #xyz
```

> Is there any efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are many edge cases when dealing with paths that a simple split on '/' does not handle. For example, `/cygwin/home/learn/xyz` and `/cygwin/home/learn/xyz/` will split differently. So will `/cygwin//home/learn/xyz`.

You can work around this with some thought.

```
string.split(/\/+/).reject { |p| p.empty? }
```

But that's not the only peril of manipulating paths with split. For example: you're on Windows, and you are going to get paths with `\` in them.

Instead, use [Pathname](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html) for path manipulation. It can do many, many things. [Pathname#each_filename](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/pathname/rdoc/Pathname.html#method-i-each_filename) will give you all the pieces as an array.

```
require "pathname";
# ['cygwin', 'home', 'learn', 'xyz']
puts Pathname.new("/cygwin/home/learn/xyz").each_filename.to_a
```

Even though using Pathname is about 3x slower, it's much simpler and safer, and Pathname is very useful. File manipulation is not going to be your performance bottleneck, always profile before you start optimizing. Use the time you saved not having to write and debug path manipulation code to do more important optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a big room for improvements, but there are two:

```
_, _, home, _, dir = "/cygwin/home/learn/xyz".split('/')
home
#⇒ "home"
dir
#⇒ "xyz"
```

Don’t split by regexp when you can split by string and don’t produce intermediate array objects.

---

Also, one might use regexp here (it’s less efficient, but probably more generic):

```
m = "/cygwin/home/learn/xyz".match(
       %r|\A/\w+/(?<home>\w+)/\w+/(?<dir>\w+)\z|)
m.captures
#⇒ ["home", "xyz"]
m[:home]
#⇒ "home"
m[:dir]
#⇒ "xyz"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dir1, dir2 = path.split('/').reject{|p| p.empty?}.values_at(1,3)
```